# How to show loading in button for API requests

Tags: angular

I want to show loading circle in button when user click it, for each button click I send related inputs value with HTTP request show loading

Now one way I use is to declare a boolean variable for each button to change before and after send request

```
showLoading: boolean = false;

userClick() {
  this.showLoading = true;
  // send http request here
  this.showLoading = false;
}
```

And in component HTML template use this boolean variable to show or hide loading circle

```html
<span *ngIf="showLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

One idea for manage all states is defined this booleans in one object such as:

```js
buttonLoading = {
  firstLoading: false,
  secoundLoading: false
}
```

Comment: subscribe to http-request and disable the loading bar there... or write http-interceptor which will do it for all requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is to set `showLoading` to `false` once you have subscribed the the service method that makes the request. You will be required to wait for the response by returning the observable values.

HTTP request are asynchronous, thus we will have to set it to false within the `subscribe()` block, and not outside of it.

```
showLoading: boolean = false;

userClick() {
  this.showLoading = true;
  this.sampleService.getDate().subscribe(response => {
    // once response is returned,
    this.showLoading = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: my request work correctly but i want to have method for disable each button loading after response.

Comment: @AliZareshahi this is what my code does. Since you have already binded the spinner to the ngIf condition, it will be conditionally rendered when `userClick()` is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a loadingButton.component that contains your button and loading element.

Then you should create a function in loadingButton.component that get url, data and 
method.

By defined ViewChild you can call this function.

easy :)

Comment: i can now improve and share this component as module for other people ;)
thanks